# $(selector).css('width','+=value') doesn't work

Tags: jquery

css:

```
#obj { display:block; width:10%; height:30px; background-color:#006600; }
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#obj').css('width','+=10');

});
```

html:

```
<span id="obj"></span>
```

it won't grow.

Comment: .css('width','+=10');, is an accepded syntax As of jQuery 1.6. , +=10 adds 10 px, always unless you use % in the jQ

Comment: it [worked](http://jsfiddle.net/WyR6q/) for me using jquery 1.6.4. What's the version of jquery that you're using?

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#obj').width($('#obj').width()+10)

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvmwu/

**--------Edit---------------**

I just checked jQuery resources: your code is correct too , but for that you need jQuery version 1.6+

try this http://jsfiddle.net/nvmwu/2/  with different versions of jQuery

-----------Extract from Jquery Api--------

*As of **jQuery 1.6**, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, **.css( "padding-left", "+=15" )** would result in a total padding-left **of 25px**.*

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: .css('width','+=10');, is an accepded syntax As of jQuery 1.6

Comment: hum maybe it won't work cuz <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @rpbd: yes you need to have jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $('#obj').css('width', function () {
    return $(this).width() + 10;
  });
});
```

Comment: (that was the last time)

Comment: Recursively self-unfulfilling prophesy

Comment: I am bewildered by the fact that you somehow managed to remember this post *and* came back to it, too.

Comment: I didn't; I got an upvote on my answer and the subsequent notification in blackbeard's black bar. Sometimes I follow those for nostalgia's sakes.

Answer (score 2):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vr3Px/) in FF5, but [only as of jQuery 1.6](http://jsfiddle.net/sT278/), and your comments elsewhere indicate that you are using jQuery 1.5.2.

In fact, [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) even *says* this:

> **As of jQuery 1.6**, .css() accepts
>   relative values similar to .animate().
>   Relative values are a string starting
>   with += or -= to increment or
>   decrement the current value. For
>   example, if an element's padding-left
>   was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15"
>   ) would result in a total padding-left
>   of 25px.

Please read it next time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using jQuery 1.6.1. Updated to 1.7.1 and it works.

Looks like this was fixed in 1.6.2. From the release notes:

".css() doesn’t work with relative values on hyphenated properties"

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9237
http://blog.jquery.com/2011/06/30/jquery-162-released/